# How to receive a ajax callback in ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using AJAX with my CodeIgniter application.
I've manged to make a "Ajax checkbox", so when I click on my checkbox, in background specific function is called.
But **how to make a callback, I mean I would like to know if the operation was done ok, or maybe it was any problem/error**.

My HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="change_parameter(<?=$dane_leada['lead_id']?>, 'my_parameter');" >
```

JS:

```
function change_parameter(lead_id, parametr)
{
    $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
    url     : '<?=base_url();?>leads/change_parametr/' + lead_id,
        data    : "lead_id=" + lead_id,
    data    : "parameter=" + parameter,
    });

    alert("Status changed"); //here should be message "ok" or "error"

}
```

PHP in Controller:

```
public function change_parameter($lead_id, $parametr=FALSE)
    {

        if  ($lead_id != "" AND isset($_POST['parameter']))         
        {
            $parameter = $_POST['parameter'];                   //odczytujemy zmienną wysłaną przez AJAXa
        }

        if ($data['dane_leada'][$parameter] == '0') $new_parameter = 1; else $new_parameter = 0;

        $dane = array(
            'lead_id'   => $lead_id,
            $parameter  => $new_parameter,
        );

        $this->model_leady->mofify_lead($lead_id, $dane);

        // return error or confirm
    }
```

Comment: By using the succes function of an ajax call?

Comment: Change your data to `data: { lead_id: lead_id, parameter: parameter }` and In controller send response using `echo 'success' or your error message`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the script with this:

```
function change_parameter(lead_id, parametr)
{
    $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : '<?=base_url();?>leads/change_parametr/' + lead_id,
        data    : {lead_id : lead_id,parameter :parameter},
        success: function(response){
            if(response){
               alert("Status changed"); //here should be message "ok" or "error"
            }else{
               alert("ERROR :Something Wrong");
            }

        },
        error: function (err) {
          alert("ERROR :Something Wrong");
     });
    });
}
```

Or You can add error handler.

```
error: function (err) {
   alert("ERROR :" + err.status);
}
```

Comment: @messerbill if needed we can add the error handler as well.

Comment: @Toretto
I am not sure how I can get an response.
I've changed your code like above + I've added in my PHP extra line:
echo 'success';

Code works but I never receive any confirmation message.
Could you please be more precise what I need to do?

Comment: @Tikky tried to print your response under the success function of your ajax call. Check what your are getting as response.

Comment: ok, it was a problem with another echo. Now I am getting alert if everythings works fine, but when it is an error I am not getting anything. How to add another message if will be no response or error?

Comment: @Tikky Just add else condition :). see updated answer.

Comment: It is not so easy. In my real example I have a condition in PHP script to check if the user can change a parameter and if not I call a [show_error](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html) funtion. Then I am not getting any alert (response) via Ajax.

Comment: @Tikky You can do one thing if user cannot change the parameter then send the response as 0 or false(just to check at the script) and if can change the parameter simply send the response and check at script. for example if(response!=0){alert('sucess');}else{alert('Error')}

Comment: @Toretto Thank you for help.
BTW. Errors now working fine, after I've added "err.status" instead of "err" in your code.